# Ionic/AngularJS ng-click event not firing?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, css, ionic-framework

I am just playing around withe Ionic/AngularJS. I can't get alert window to show up ? I started ionic with a blank template. The app actually launches in the browser window, but when the button is pressed, nothing happens.

```js
// Ionic Starter App

// angular.module is a global place for creating, registering and retrieving Angular modules
// 'starter' is the name of this angular module example (also set in a <body> attribute in index.html)
// the 2nd parameter is an array of 'requires'
var App = angular.module('freshlyPressed', ['ionic']);

App.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
});

App.controller( 'AppCtrl' , function($scope, $log)
{
 $scope.refresh = function()
 {
  window.alert("Hello");
 }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="freshlyPressed" data-ng-control="AppCtrl">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title>Freshly Pressed</title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script> 
  </head>
  <body>
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-balanced">
       <h1 class="title">Freshly Pressed</h1>
    <button type="button" class="button" ng-click="refresh()">
              <i class="icon ion-refresh"></i>
          </button>
   </ion-header-bar>
   <ion-content>
       <h1>Some Contents</h1>
   </ion-content>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless Ionic does something very different than Angular, you have `data-ng-control` and it should be `data-ng-controller`.